# How do I configure vpc to allow outbound traffic over customer gateway

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet, amazon-vpc

I have configured a vpc to communicate with an on-prem private network as outlined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html) I am able to ping servers in my on-prem network through the virtual gateway. I have two private subnets and my route table associated with each of those subnets is configured as below:

```
10.255.254.0/23  local
0.0.0.0/0        vgw-xxxxxxx
```

My expectation is that all of my traffic, internet or otherwise is being communicated over the vgw to the cgw and then be subject to our on-premise firewall policies.  In fact the article linked above specifically says that is the case:

> The instances in the VPN-only subnet can't reach the Internet directly; any Internet-bound traffic must first traverse the virtual private gateway to your network, where the traffic is then subject to your firewall and corporate security policies.

When running a server on one of the private subnets the output from traceroute looks like this:

[image: traceroute internal ip]

My traceroute to www.google.com looks like this:

[image: traceroute to google]

as you can see from above traffic to www.google.com is just dying on the first hop.

I know that this can be achieved by adding a NAT to the public subnet, but I would prefer that all traffic flow through the on prem network instead.

What piece am I missing to make this work?

Comment: In the VPN Connection configuration in VPC, under Static IP Prefixes, do you have 0.0.0.0/0 declared?  Or just your corporate network address space?  The `!N` in the traceroute means "network unreachable" and 169.254.249.5 appears to be the inside interface of the VPC's VPN hardware, rejecting the traffic due to lack of a route there.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot we just have corporate network address space in the static ip prefixes. do you think we need to set static prefixes for 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Yes, since in the scenario you are discussing, you want the tunnel to accept traffic for all Internet destinations.